# Joomla using left "sidebar a" when using warp framework

Tags: templates, frameworks, joomla3.0, warp

I'm currently trying to make a website using Joomla. I have found a very nice template that suits my needs, but there is a problem when I try to use the left "sidebar a" spot (http://demos.themekat.com/fsmods)- it appears on the right. I've researched the problem and found that I need to specify which one to use (http://www.yootheme.com/themes/warp-framework), but I can't find how. So, can you please help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

It's inside your template configuration (Layout)

Under Sidebars, you are gonna see:

Choose the sidebar widths and align the sidebar to the left or right.

```
Position    Width   Alignment
sidebar-a   25%     left
sidebar-b   25%     right
```